# Illustrator result is pixelated when printed

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I drew an A4 chart on AI. It has a grid with cells and they contain textual values. Additionally, my image contains header and footer with lines and text. I exported it as png-24 image and when printed it all comes pixelated. How to have a smooth result on a print?

Comment: I 'Save for Web' and there is no DPI option there. But the Effects>Document Raster Effects Settings is set to High (300 ppi)

Comment: Why are you using 'Save for *Web*' if you are *printing*?

Comment: Just to put the first comment in context, I asked what DPI they were exporting the PNG at.  Using Save For Web is _definitely_ the wrong way to go...I thought you were using the actual export command, like you stated in your question.

Comment: What pixel size are you exporting at? Save for web defaults to 72ppi, at which an A4 is 595x842 pixels, which will look pixelated when printed. A4 at 300ppi is 2480x3508 pixels, if you *absolutely have to* export a PNG then it needs to be closer to that size—but as Manly said, just export a PDF.

Comment: Unnecessary down vote here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and easiest answer I can give you is *not* to export it as a PNG in the first place.

**Export your file as a PDF** and that should solve your problem.

PNG is a raster image format, whereas a PDF will be able to maintain the vectorized versions of any text, shapes, or other objects created inside AI.

Answer (score -1):

The Real answer here is to ensure you have the proper print driver. most print management servers only use basic PCL drivers. you will need to download the MAC

Comment: If you save as PDF as @Manly answered.. it doesn't matter.